# Permutation operator and second quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, notation, many-body

I just read that a permutation operator $P_{i,j}$ acts on a product state $|a_1,...,a_n \rangle \in H^n$ by

$$P_{i,j} |a_1,...,a_i,a_j,...a_n\rangle  = |a_1,...,a_j,a_i,...a_n \rangle .$$
Now my question is: In this notation, what do the $a_1,..,a_n$ denote and what does the position in the product-state $|a_1,...,a_n\rangle $ denote, somehow I have troubles to distinguish between these two things.

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the specifics what the notation means, but in general one might say: we pretend, mathematically, that we can label each particle $1, 2, \dots n$, and look at its individual distribution in space, which is (for pure states) some wavefunction $a_k(\vec r, t)$. The product state simply means "particle #1 is in state $a_1$, particle #2 is in state $a_2$..." and so on.

So we're talking about swapping the wavefunctions of two individual particles: swapping "where they are" in the world.

It may help if you have, say, a single-particle Hamiltonian $\hat H^0$ with a set of single-particle eigenfunctions $\hat H^0 |E_m\rangle = E_m |E_m\rangle$. You can then write (for **any** Hamiltonian, even totally unrelated ones) the actual multi-particle state $|\Psi\rangle$ in terms of product states of the $|E_m\rangle$ kets.